# Regex to count and print matched characters

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have the following strings:

```
5/29/11, 11:28 AM - Chris: But I was also first in my radar class in the Navy, and that was a class of twenty. 
Can I say something? I’m the type of person, if you ask me a question, and I don’t know the answer, I’m gonna tell you that I don’t know. 
But I bet you what. I know how to find the answer, and I will find the answer. Is that fair enough?

5/29/11, 11:28 AM - Interviewer 2: Chris. 
What would you say if a guy walked in for an interview without a shirt on and I hired him? 
What would you say?

5/29/11, 11:28 AM - Chris: He must’ve had on some really nice pants.
```

I am doing some text analysis, I have to count and print characters in each string. For example, the above string will become:

```
5/29/11, 11:28 AM - Chris (331): But I was also first in my radar class in the Navy, and that was a class of twenty. 
Can I say something? I’m the type of person, if you ask me a question, and I don’t know the answer, I’m gonna tell you that I don’t know. 
But I bet you what. I know how to find the answer, and I will find the answer. Is that fair enough?

5/29/11, 11:28 AM - Interviewer 2 (127): Chris. 
What would you say if a guy walked in for an interview without a shirt on and I hired him? 
What would you say?

5/29/11, 11:28 AM - Chris (41): He must’ve had on some really nice pants.
```

I am using Sublime Text, and I am able to match the strings. However, how do I get hold of the count value in a variable, which can be printed? Here is my Regex which matches the initial timestamp and person name:
`[\w\/\,\ \:\-]+:`

Comment: Finding string length is not done in regex

Comment: Sounds like an easy enough one-liner: `perl -00 -lpe 's/: /sprintf " (%d): ", length() - $+[0]/e'`. But why use Sublime for it?